# drawing shapes based on data read from excel sheet

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am trying to draw ellipses and circles and label them with the data read from an excel sheet. I am able to read the excel sheet now using Apache POI. Can anybody suggest what library and functionality of java apache poi can be used for drawing. Swing will make my application slow. Hence I am using apache poi.